Getting data into a manager.dict and sharing it between processes
I'm currently trying to teach myself how to handle live data by streaming Forza telemetry data from my xbox to my PC. I'm having issues storing that data in a manager.dict and sharing it to other processes. I've created a manager.dict called packets, here is the app.py:
from connectors.forza_connect import forza_connect, forza_record
from telemetry_utils import throttle
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        packets = manager.dict({})   # Create shared dict for the worker and UI to use
    
        # Start the background data collection process
        data_args = ('motorsport', packets, )                      
        data_process = Process(target=forza_connect, args=data_args)  
        data_process.start()

        throttle_process = Process(target=throttle.show_throttle_text, args=(packets, ))
        throttle_process.start()

        data_process.join()
        throttle_process.join()

This runs forza_connect which collects the data and transforms it into a dictionary, this bit works fine on its own but it doesn't seem to send that data back in to packets. Here's the forza_connect.py:
import socket
from data_utils import forza_data   

def forza_connect(game_version, packets, local_ip='0.0.0.0', port=5555, to_print=False, fd=forza_data):

    ## Connect to Forza
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((local_ip, port))
    #sock.settimeout(5)

    fd = fd.ForzaData(game_version)

    while True:
        packet, packet_source = sock.recvfrom(1024) # Receive data
        fd.parse(packet)                            # Parse data             
    
        # Append packet to the shared list
        for k, v in fd.to_dict().items():
            packets[k] = v
    
    sock.close()                                    # Close the socket

I want the data collected above to be available to multiple processes, however no data seems to be being stored and no data is getting sent to throttle.py
# Show throttle percentage as text
def show_throttle_text(forza_data):
    while True:
        #print(f"\r throttle percentage: {int(forza_data['throttle'])}", end='', flush=True)
        print(forza_data)

This currently just showing an empty dict. What is it I am mis-understanding about how to use this? Thanks

A Manager can't detect changes in containers (here: lists) which are values of a managed dict (or managed list). See https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects. After the append call add a line packets[k] = packets[k] to inform the dict about the change. Alternatively you can use managed lists as values of the managed dict.

There are multiple problems here. packets is not a dict of lists, it is just a dict, so there is no append method. forza_connect is an infinite loop that will update packets endlessly. On the other hand, show_throttle_text will print immediately and terminate, so it will likely terminate before the first packet arrives. IMO, you may want to use Queue or Pipe.

Yeah I fixed the non-loop in throttle. I've currently got it working just continuously outputting to a json file but I'll check out Queue and Pip. Thanks

I solved this by continually exporting data as a json file and reading from that instead of using a shared dictionary.
